# 'Element enableLazyInitialization is not allowed here' when I add plugin for bytecode enhancement

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, maven-plugin, dropwizard, byte-code-enhancement

I am trying to enable bytecode enhancement so that I can do lazy loading for the OneToOne mappings in my entity class.
This is the plugin I have added in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is the entity class:

```
public class ServiceItemUnit {
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @Convert(converter = PaymentDetailConverter.class)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "serviceItemUnit", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private PaymentDetail paymentDetail;
}
```

This is the child class:

```
public class PaymentDetail {
@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_item_unit_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @JsonBackReference("service_item_unit_id")
    private ServiceItemUnit serviceItemUnit;
}
```

I went through this article, where the author guided to use this plugin for enabling bytecode enhancement.